# Rewrite txt files into one txt file + go to the line every time

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to take data from a certain number of text files called "sobelPix[i].txt" and rewrite them in a single text file called "newData.txt". So, all data coming from one "sobelPix" file should be one line in the "newData" file.

My problem is that instead of going to the line everytime the program prints the data from a new "sobelPix" file, it just over-writes over the same first line. So, eventually, I end up with only the data from the last "sobelPix" file.
I'm not sure how to iterate through the lines of the "newData" file, as it is suppose to be an empty file...

Can you help me??
Thank you!

My code:

```
    i = 0
    while not (i == 2):
        o = open("sobelPix" + str(i) + ".txt", "r")
        l = open("newData.txt", "w+")
            num = 0
        lines = o.readlines()

        print("sobelPix" + str(i) + ".txt")

        for line in lines:  
            r, g, b = map(int, line.split())    
            l.write(str(num) + ":"+ str((r+g+b)//3) + "  ")
            num += 1

        #pb: it's never going to the line
        #l.write("\n")  

        i += 1
```

Comment: You open the two files each time, but never close them. You could just move the opening of newData before the while, then close it after the cycle

Answer (score 0):

I think Jackopo got it right, you were opening the newData.txt file multiple times without ever closing it.  Try something like this (untested):

```
i = 0

l = open("newData.txt", "w+")

while (i < 2):
    o = open("sobelPix" + str(i) + ".txt", "r")

    num = 0
    lines = o.readlines()

    print("sobelPix" + str(i) + ".txt")

    for line in lines:  
        r, g, b = map(int, line.split())    
        l.write(str(num) + ":"+ str((r+g+b)//3) + "  ")
        num += 1

    #pb: it's never going to the line
    #l.write("\n")  

    o.close()
    i += 1 

l.close()
```